# How to setup CI/CD to ASP.Net project on EC2 instance with AWS CodeDeploy?

Tags: asp.net, amazon-ec2, cicd, aws-codepipeline, aws-code-deploy

I currently have an ASP.NET project running on an AWS EC2 Windows instance. I'm looking to configure CI/CD for this project. I've previously used AWS CodePipeline and CodeDeploy for other projects, and I'm considering using these services again.

While I understand how to push code to the destination folder using the CodeDeploy agent, I'm uncertain about the process of building the ASP.NET project and deploying it. (Maybe I am wrong.)

If anyone has experience setting up CI/CD for an ASP.NET project on an EC2 instance, could you please share insights or steps on how to accomplish this?

Thank you in advance.